# two-way data binding in angularjs not able to bind my value in controller side

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working in ionic and I use Ubuntu and chrome for seeing my logs and here I am trying to bind my data what user enters into an object so that I can post the user entered value to the server.

my html looks like

```
<ion-modal-view ng-controller="SignInCtrl">
  <ion-header-bar>
    <button class="button ion-chevron-left" ng-click="signUpBack()" >Back</button>
    <div class="h1 title">Form Validation</div>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <div class="list">
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">UserName</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="John" data-ng-model="formUserName">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Name</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Suhr" data-ng-model="formName">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Email</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="john@suhr.com" data-ng-model="formEmail">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Password</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="sdftw" data-ng-model="formPassword">
      </label>
    </div>

    <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="createUser()">
      Create Account
    </button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

and my controller here please check my formPost where i am trying to bind the user entered value in formPost variable.

```
app.controller('SignInCtrl',['$scope','$http','$state',function($scope,$http,$state){
  console.log('invoking SignInCtrl');

  $scope.signUpBack = function(){
    $state.go('details');
  };

  $scope.createUser = function(){      

    var formPost = {
      "Username":$scope.formUserName,
      "Name":$scope.formName,
      "EmailID":$scope.formEmail,
      "Password":$scope.formPassword
    };
    console.log(formPost);

    $http.post("http://aflaree.com/qrcodeservice/Service1.svc/Signupsupervisor", formPost)
      .success(function(response){
        console.log(response);

      if(!response.Response ){
        alert(response.Response);
        $state.go('login');
      }
        else{
          alert('error');
        }
      })
      .error(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        alert(' error Username already exist');
      });
  };
}]);
```

In console.log(formPost); i am getting undefined value but i need the user entered value in there any idea.

Thanks

Comment: any error you are facing?

Comment: no error still now

Comment: s in console.log(formPost); i am getting undefined value in username,name,...

Comment: try to send the values differently , differently i mean, create an empty array in controller like `$scope.Myarray =[]` now in place of username and email etc try to change ng-model like this `Myarray.formUserName`  and on ng-click of `createUser` try to pass the method like this `createUser(Myarray)` and in controller you can access the individual values like `"Username":Myarray.formUserName`. please give a try and tell me it works or not

Comment: without using $scope.formUserName how it is possible to bind the data to array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106969/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-webruster).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might simplify it:

```js
app.controller('SignInCtrl',['$scope','$http','$state',function($scope,$http,$state){
  console.log('invoking SignInCtrl');

  $scope.signUpBack = function(){
    $state.go('details');
  };

  $scope.createUser = function(form){      

    console.log(form);

    $http.post("http://aflaree.com/qrcodeservice/Service1.svc/Signupsupervisor", form)
      .success(function(response){
        console.log(response);

      if(!response.Response ){
        alert(response.Response);
        $state.go('login');
      }
        else{
          alert('error');
        }
      })
      .error(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        alert(' error Username already exist');
      });
  };
}]);
```

```html
<ion-modal-view ng-controller="SignInCtrl">
  <ion-header-bar>
    <button class="button ion-chevron-left" ng-click="signUpBack()" >Back</button>
    <div class="h1 title">Form Validation</div>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <div class="list">
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">UserName</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="John" data-ng-model="form.UserName">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Name</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Suhr" data-ng-model="form.Name">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Email</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="john@suhr.com" data-ng-model="form.Email">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
        <span class="input-label">Password</span>
        <input type="text" placeholder="sdftw" data-ng-model="form.Password">
      </label>
    </div>

    <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="createUser(form)">
      Create Account
    </button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

Comment: i was using the same method which i use in question for login form it works fine but can i know the reson why it is not working in this form

Comment: To be honest also the way you used works fine to me locally!

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ol244At5Yd4RMyuoChA4   Please chek this one on console.log i am not able see the user entered data in my object formPost

Comment: Button's event not working, anyway debugging in plnkr is not easy!

Comment: i have gone through so many videos but not able to find how its works and also I am not getting any error

Comment: I have doubt here **form** is used so is this the way for two way data binding

Comment: This is two-way data-binding, but in this case you are just taking data from UI to send to backend you are not directly displaying them since this is a modal dialog, so for you its enough to get them once and send to backend on submit.